# migration from mysql to nosql database in production without code change and mysql without foreign keys and indexes

Tags: mysql, database-design, architecture, database-migration

i have two scenarios here :

1. migrating mysql database to nosql without code change(no orms are used)
2. using no foriegn keys and indexes in mysql(because they want to migrate to different database in future)
   3.all this done by very less code change

these questions are asked by my team lead. so i dont have a answer to give him properly because i feel it very unlikely to do mysql with no indexes and foreign keys and first of all if they are not meant to use mysql.then why they choose that.

1. i want to know that people do like this in software industries
   ofently or they will choose on their need fits correctly
2. they are saying that foreign key validitations are done by api level
   not by mysql level

i dont understand them becasue i have less experience so i dont have an answer why they are saying like this. please give me some insight to this that if this is a good practice or not ?

Comment: Not sure about migrating from MySQL to nosql but some nosql dbs don’t support transaction management for the sake of speed. Foreign key validations are done by MySQL. If not you would run into lot of integrity errors

Comment: @PraveenE what happen if the foreign key validations done by code? and if we do not use foreign key then the fetch operation will cost so much right?

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. "give me some insight " is not an on-topic question. There are many questions & answers about relational vs non-relational DBs & DBMSs, how is this not a duplicate? PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: FKs are not a requirement for a database.  Valid code does not need FKs, especially if the code is doing the equivalent of FK checks.  Ad hoc write queries are where FKs are useful for catching mistakes.  Indexes are not a requirement, but performance suffers.  For tiny datasets, this does not matter; for large datasets, it is deadly.

Comment: @RickJames they need perfomance and everything without fks and indexing.and also its a multitenant application so dataset become very huge in future

Comment: "Without indexing" + "very huge" = "disaster"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible without adding code - you need to implement how your data is managed by your nosql dB engine in some way. If the project is coded with a clear separation of business logic and database code, it's a simple matter of using the new database implementation instead of the old one. If that is not the case and your db implementation leaked into your business logic, then it will not be possible to switch without changing code. Depending on the size of the code base it might /will most likely be too expensive.

If you want to see an example of a clean separation of dB logic from business logic, have a look at this repository: https://github.com/fathersson/money-transfer
(this is not my repository, I just stumbled upon it today)

If you want to learn and understand the principles driving that design, start by looking for "clean architecture" and/or "Domain Driven Design" - the first one is easier to understand in my opinion and there are some talks on YouTube by Robert C. Martin that you can have a look at before buying some books.

Edit: The project I'm working on at the moment did change from postgresql running on rds to dynamodb using a different repository without changing any existing business logic. It saves a lot of money that way. So yes, changing the db backend does happen and is driven by requirements.

In addition to that, when I start working on a new feature set/micro service/bounded context I usually start with a simple in memory repository implementation that's using a map. After I'm done with the initial set of use cases, I know more about the db requirements and choose the db engine based on these and the general requirement to limit the number of different technologies in use.

Comment: what will be the consequences of not using **foreign key** relation ships and other indexing methods like **unique key** in mysql.is there any problem.

Comment: The way you index is in implementation detail of the repository and hence depends on the DB engine the repository is using. Indexes are used to locate data in an efficient /fast way. They are also used to validate data integrity, email addresses in the user's table being unique is a prominent example for this case. Generally, you want to handle as many business rules in your business logic as possible, and the ones you can't handle there, have to handled by the repository - like a unique constraint over 100k rows of data.

Comment: Foreign keys are either required or a result of data normalization. The latter are not that important, since data duplication is something that's acceptable in most cases because of the reduced coupling and sometimes even performance benefits data duplication can bring. When used to reference another business entity and not aggregate root (that's the object the repository is persisting) its again the responsibility and hence choice of the repository implementation to not use them at all or how to deal with them.

Comment: Foreign keys referencing other aggregate roots are more complex. In the world of micro services, that'll be the id's returned by another service. The service having a reference to another services aggregate roots usually does not (want to) have access to the other services database engine. So your service needs to handle inconsistent foreign keys or use some implementation of distributed transactions when modifying data. Distributed sagas are able to deal with the most complex scenarios, local sagas might do the trick or a simple UnsupportedOperationException - depending on your use case

Comment: I don't know about your service, but the questions you are asking make me believe that you are working on a DB centric monolithic application. These projects are usually slaves to the DB engine and don't enslave the DB engine. These code bases are usually very expensive to migrate/refactor. If you are the one who might be responsible for that operation I'd recommend you to be careful. It's not impossible, but you need the support from management and the team to get this job done and that also involves changing the way you and your team is coding.

Comment: currently we are using transactions a lot so its not ideal to move to another database like no-sql because it will not provide any tranaction.but like unique  and other things we are not handling from db side.but it will cost more time on coding and make things much complex.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that and that I killed your spirit. I'd still encourage you to dive into the topic using a small example project and to play with it. Dynodb supports transactions as well as postgresql supports json and transactions which makes it essentially the same thing as dynamodb in that regard.